# Disable /wp-admin/plugin-install.php

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

How can I disable plugin upload and installation via Wordpress Admin?

Should still be able to activate/deactivate plugins in admin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a constant you can [define in `wp-config.php`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#disable-plugin-and-theme-update-and-installation) to do this.

It will also disable the theme edit, however.

```
<?php
// somewhere in wp-config.php

define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

That will remove the plugin and theme file editor (which are a terrible idea anyway) and remove the ability to install plugins and themes from the admin area.